# "Function is not available" error in Access?

Tags: ms-access

We have a new contractor at my work, who is going to be using a DB that I currently use, taking over some of my tasks.

When I run the macro we use (which had about 15 queries inside), everything is fine. But when she is running it, on about the 6th query down, she gets this error:

```
Function is not available in expressions in query expression 'IIf(Len([Applicant_SSN])<2 And Right([MedicareClaimNumber],1)="A",[MedicareClaimNumber],IIf([Male]="X",[Applicant_SSN] & "A",[Applicant_SSN] & "B"))'
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why they would not be able to run this simple line?

This is not done in a VBA function - it's used in the query front end.

Comment: It can be a missing reference or a compilation error. Bring the VBA window (ALT-F11) and hit Debug > Compile. Does it compile?

Comment: what happens when you take this line and try to execute it in the msaccess sql editor ?

Comment: if it compiles perfectly on your machine, its probably reference missing, make sure you follow this: http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/AccessReferenceErrors.html

Answer (score 0):

What wasn't obvious to me was that it doesn't have to be the library it is complaining about. Turns out that if *any* library is missing, it will complain about the first function it hits.

This routine was helpful in tracking down the issue. None of mine complained. Violating library just wasn't in the list.

```
Sub ViewReferenceDetails()
Dim ref As Reference

   For Each ref In Access.References
      PostToLog "ViewReferenceDetails", ref.NAME & " - " & 
      ref.Major & "." & ref.Minor & " -" & ref.FullPath
   Next ref
End Sub
```